# Looping background (png image) in Blender for a car chase scene

Tags: image, drivers, world, interpolation

While animating a car chase scene I need to have a background image (that includes trees, buildings etc) which moves from right to left and gets repeated in loops. I Couldn't find any driver or interpolation to create such a dynamic effect. Can someone post an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

That's not too hard actually:

I just move the UV coordinates around.

- Create a seamless background image. Left and right borders should match.
- UV-Map it on a plane that fills your background.
- Use the Node Editor for the material and create this node setup:

[image: moving UV]

The texture coordinates are provided to a Vector Math node. There, I am adding both vectors together, animating the yellow, formerly static one. Just click the button, set the X value, exist and set a key frame. It simply creates an offset for your UV coordinates, shifting the image around the plane.

[image: vector values]

As many frames as you want later, crank the value up and set another key frame. With the node selected, go into the Graph Editor and set the interpolation to linear in order to get a nice and smooth motion.

[image: linear interpolation]

I deleted the other two channels since the motion is only in one axis.

Only drawback is that motion blur won't work with Cycles. You could blur the texture though.

Comment: -thanks for the solution.I managed to get the same result by importing the image in 3d view, multiplying it along the path to be followed  and then  animating the camera.

Answer (score 0):

@Haunt_House - I was testing your solution.As shown in the gif below ,UV displacement values  are  clearly  registered in the grapheditor(0.5 to 200 over 100 frames) but in the 3d view their is no displacement.Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: try in rendered view, textured view takes a few shortcuts

Comment: @rob - thanks- it worked!However, it doesn't work in any other view.

Comment: There is a simpler "Keyframe" method to achieve the above result.Set the background texture on a plane and then goto ImageOffset (World-Properties- Textures) and keyframe (press'I')the texture displacement at appropriate locations in the timeline.Then, headover to the grapheditor and set the modifier of the displacement to "cyclic" to have it loop.